# using pool to conect a SQL server db , error in query , field use accents

Tags: sql, r, database, dplyr

I´ve a connection to a DB (SQL Server) using `pool` in the DB. I'd like to search for a field that has names with accents (Spanish), so if I run the query in SQL Management Studio it runs fine:

```sql
SELECT almanombre, estado
FROM tablaGeneral
WHERE almanombre = 'Almacén General'
```

In R this is the code:

```
pool <- dbPool(odbc::odbc(),
           dsn      = "MySQLSW",
           driver   = "SQL Server Native Client 11.0",
           server   = "ASUS\\mipc",
           database = "almacen",
           uid      = Sys.getenv("userid"),
           pwd      = Sys.getenv("pwd"))


all_combos  <-  tbl(pool,"tablaGeneral") 

#### My query

z <- all_combos %>% filter(almanombre == "Almacén General") %>% select(almanombre) %>% collect()
```

The result of it is 0 rows. If use the `show_query`, it shows:

```sql
<SQL>
SELECT "almanombre"
FROM "tablaGeneral"
WHERE ("almanombre" = 'Almacén General')
```

Comment: You don't need to specify driver and server if you've set the dsn. Are you sure your query is executed in the desired database? What does `all_combos` shows you without any filters?

Comment: The query runs fine if i dont use without accents .. example .. almanombre == "General" executes fine .. the problem its words with accents .